# chef-solo copying resources to cache directory

Tags: file, copy, chef-solo

I'm trying to copy all the files and folder that are under the "files" directory which contains all the resources of a recipe to the cache directory of chef.
I'm using this:

```
cookbook_file test_file do
  path "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/some_file"
  action :create_if_missing
  mode 0755
end
```

which works fine but this is just a single file. I want to do it for all files and directories. I tried using wild cards "*" which did not work. There might be something like a  search or filter that can do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need remote_directory. eg:

```
remote_directory '/tmp/remote_folder' do
    source 'folder_under_files'
    owner 'foo'
    group 'bar'
    mode "0744"
end
```

See http://docs.opscode.com/resource_remote_directory.html

We use it with chef-solo just fine.